# Edit and delete rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, ado.net, datagridview

We know asp.net gridview can edit/delete by clicking the button along with the gridview bind with a database.
Can we do it in windows form?  I mean how to customize the button event or borrow asp.net framework to winform?
Please see the image.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the winform grid do not have these abilities, You'll have to create them explicitly, like add another column and implement his onlclick/doulbe click, it really have tons of events.
p.s. if u want the user to change values on the rows displayed you'll need this:
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke

Comment: Can we do it by ADO.NET Entity Data model?